# Check list overlap with list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension, overlap

I have a script in python that generate 2 random lists with different sizes and return a third list that contains only the elements that are common between the 2 lists (**without duplicates**) using list comprehensions

***Example:***

```
a = [3, 8, 9, 6, 5, 3, 7, 8, 2, 10]
b = [7, 13, 20, 12, 12, 2, 6, 1, 2, 8, 19, 3, 15, 16, 14, 22, 22, 4, 9, 15, 8, 13]
```

***My result list is***

```
c = [7, 2, 6, 2, 8, 3, 9, 8]
```

***But it should be***

```
c = [7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 9]
```

Here is what I've done:

```
c = [i for i in max(a, b) if i in min(a, b) and i not in c]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: be carefull when writing `c = [i for i in max(a, b) if i in min(a, b) and i not in c]` : when computing right expression, c is undefined and should not be used in the right part

Comment: I've initialized it before

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use sets in the following way:

```
c = list(set(a).intersection(set(b)))
```

This will give you:

```
[2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This works because `set` items are unordered, unchangeable, and do not allow duplicate values. Combine that with the [`intersection`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp) method you will get the result.

Answer (score 2):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), not [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
c = list(set(a) & set(b))
print(c)
# [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

> A set is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements. Basic uses include membership testing and eliminating duplicate entries. Set objects also support mathematical operations like union, intersection, difference, and symmetric difference.

Answer (score 0):

```py
    a = [3, 8, 9, 6, 5, 3, 7, 8, 2, 10]
    b = [7, 13, 20, 12, 12, 2, 6, 1, 2, 8, 19, 3, 15, 16, 14, 22, 22, 4, 9, 15, 8, 13]
    c=[]
    for i in max(a,b):
        if i in min(a, b) and i not in c:
            c.append(i) 
    print(c)
```